# ios - execute a call from my contacts

Tags: ios, iphone

I was wondering if it's possible to execute a call from my contacts through my app? What I'm trying to do is execute a phone call which contains a '#'. I know Apple does not allow this by saying @"tel://#1234". However, I was wondering if there is a workaround if the contact already exists on the users phone, and have them execute the call from there.

Comment: "To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or changing the behavior of a phone or account, the Phone application supports most, but not all, of the special characters in the tel scheme. Specifically, if a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone application does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number." - Apple, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know, Apple won't let you do that with URL schemes.  I believe the only way you could do such a thing is to use the Address Book UI framework (specifically, [ABPersionViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPersonViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007076)) to display a contact within your own view.  Check out the [Address Book Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/UI_Controllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH5-SW1) that Apple has.

Be sure you set `allowsActions` to true to enable call/text buttons.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack, but a UITextView will highlight phone numbers if you select the "Phone Numbers" checkbox under Detection in IB. This will make phone numbers tappable and they will initiate a phone call (on iPhone). You could incorporate a UITextView (read only) into a custom table cell--assuming you're using a table view to display your contacts. Styling might be an issue as I don't believe there is a way to change the highlight color or to remove the underline, however, this would enable you to initiate a call from a table view of contacts.

[image]